# how to order nested attribute by nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Users who have Profiles. I can display the Profiles like this:

```
@profiles.each do |p|
  puts p.user.last_name + " " + p.user.first_name
end
```

I don't know how to order by last_name, because it's a nested attribute and not part of the Profiles table directly. My Users model orders correctly, but not when I'm calling the user name through his profile. Thanks for any help. Should I make a "profiles_helper.rb" file or should I order in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` to convert `profiles` to array, and then you can use 
`sort_by` method to sort based on `last_name`

```
profiles = @profiles.group_by{|p| p.user.last_name}
result = profiles.sort_by{|last_name, profiles| last_name}
```